# Created graphics object only showing once and disappears again after creating another one

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

For a current project I'm learning and using Java Swing. I want my program to create rounded rectangles that I'm currently doing with `Graphics`.

I created a `JFrame` and a menu. Both are working fine. When I click my menu item "Create Sphere" you can choose a color from `ColorChooser`, define a name, width, height, x and y position. After calling the method, I get my RoundedRectangle

[image: screen capture 1]

When I want to create another one, it also works, but the first one disappears

[image: screen capture 2]

After resizing the frame, the first one appears again, but the second one is disappearing.

Code:

JFrame:

```
public void createWindow() {
    /** Frame */
    this.setTitle("Diagram");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(700,500);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

My Dialog frame calls the `createSphere` method, where I create a new `Sphere` (i.e. `RoundedRectangle`) and add it to my frame:

```
public void createSphere(String name, int width, int height, int x, int y, Color color) {
    this.add(new Sphere(name, width, height, x, y, color));
    this.validate();
}
```

Sphere Class:

```
public class Sphere extends JPanel {
    private String name;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private Color color;

    public Sphere(String name, int width, int height, int xPos, int yPos, Color color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRoundRect(this.xPos,this.yPos,this.width,this.height, 15, 15);
        g.setColor(this.color);
        g.fillRoundRect(this.xPos,this.yPos,this.width,this.height, 15, 15);
    }
```

I want my program to create several `Sphere` objects. Later, `Sphere` objects also shall contain several smaller `Sphere`s with text.

Comment: Make `Sphere` a plain Java getter/setter class.  Create a `DrawingPanel` class extending `JPanel`.  Create a `DrawingModel` class as a plain Java getter/setter class holding a `java.util.LIst` of `Sphere` objects.  Code your `DrawingPanel` class to paint a `List` of `Sphere` instances in the `paintComponent` method.

Comment: The panel gets cleared before painting the graphics, so you only see the last graphic painted. See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common approaches for doing incremental painting and see which approach best meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

@camickr (in the comments section) explained the reason as to why only the last graphic is painted. One way to approach that problem is to have a separate drawing panel (i.e., `SpherePane` below) extending `JPanel` (as @Gilbert Le Blanc also pointed out), which will be used to paint a list of Sphere objects. Every time you create a new instance of Sphere, it will be added to that list, and whenever `repaint()` is called, that list of Sphere objects will be painted in the `paintComponent` method of `SpherePane`. Below is an example, using a color chooser (as you mentioned in the question) to add new Sphere objects (once a color is chosen) of fixed size and placed in random locations (you can replace those with your own code).

**Main.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    ArrayList<Sphere> list;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenuItem menuItemCreate;
    JColorChooser jColorChooser;
    SpherePane sp;
    int max = 500;
    int min = 10;

    public Main() {
        list = new ArrayList<Sphere>();
        sp = new SpherePane(list);
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuItemCreate= new JMenuItem("Create Sphere");
        menuBar.add(menuItemCreate);
        jColorChooser = new JColorChooser();
        addJCListener();
        createWindow();
    }

    private void addJCListener() {
        menuItemCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "", Color.BLUE);
                if (c != null) {
                    int x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
                    int y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
                    createSphere("", 100, 100, x, y, c);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    private void createWindow() {
        this.add(sp);
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        this.setSize(700,500);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createSphere(String name, int width, int height, int x, int y, Color color) {
        list.add(new Sphere(name, width, height, x, y, color));
        this.repaint();
        this.revalidate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

**SpherePane.java**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SpherePane extends JPanel {
    ArrayList<Sphere> list;

    public SpherePane(ArrayList<Sphere> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Sphere s : list) {
            g.drawRoundRect(s.getxPos(), s.getyPos(), s.getWidth(), s.getHeight(), 15, 15);
            g.setColor(s.getColor());
            g.fillRoundRect(s.getxPos(), s.getyPos(), s.getWidth(), s.getHeight(), 15, 15);
        }

    }
}
```

**Sphere.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Sphere {
    private String name;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private Color color;

    public Sphere(String name, int width, int height, int xPos, int yPos, Color color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getxPos() {
        return xPos;
    }

    public int getyPos() {
        return yPos;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    
}
```